# after login facebook, the confirm(permisstions request) dialog will show time after time

Tags: android, facebook

use the android Facebook SDK, when i login, the confirm(permissions request) dialog will show time after time,and i can not granted the publish permissions, any solution?

```
private static final String PERMISSION = "publish_actions";         
// We need to get new permissions, then complete the action when
// we get called back.
session.requestNewPublishPermissions(new Session.NewPermissionsRequest(
                    mActivity, PERMISSION));
```

Comment: Please elaborate more. How about codes or screenshots.

Comment: I'm also having this issue with my test application. really looking forward for any answer there might be

Comment: when i login, the facebook sdk will show the dialog all the time, screenshots  like this : https://fbcdn-dragon-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-xfp1/t39.2087-6/10574701_757808774261036_122447541_n.png